# How to position a image overflowing the edge (right-bottom) of a div?

Tags: html, css, ios, cordova, position

Is there any way to position an image at the bottom of a div (overflowing the div edge), after the div has been filled with an undefined amount of text?

The image is meant to be half way inside the div and half way outside the div - overflowing the edge (if you know what I mean) - I have managed to do this with the use of a relative position and a static layout (in pixels). This does however not work when the div height is dynamic (height=auto;).

I have a html structure like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <p>X amount of text</p>
    </div>
    <img class="button" src="../images/image.png"></img>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.button
{
    position:relative;
    right: 30px;
    #bottom:-103px;
    #bottom: 70%;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Also when the image is clicked the box expands. This is done with the following code (and works perfectly):

```
var boxHeight = $('.box').height();
var boxHeightOffset = 5 - boxHeight;
$('.button').css('bottom', boxHeightOffset + "px");
```

I have tried with bottom: % but that clearly does nothing. I have tried to run my little javascript function when the view loads but however I try to implement that - I get height=0.

This question might be a bit complicated but what I'm wondering is if there is any way to either run the javascript at a correct time (on div load - somehow) or edit my css to be more dynamic?

Oh, and I'm using PhoneGap on iOS. (Webkit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
#container {
  position:relative;
}         

.button { 
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px;
  right:-20px;
}
```

If that doesn't work, how about using negative right and bottom margins instead?

Comment: And you solved it. Thanks! The only adjustment was that bottom:-20px; did not work. I don't understand why. I changed it to margin-bottom:-20px; and everything worked. I could even delete my javascript code! Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to say thank you. I'm really glad it worked.